# How to get "My Reviews" from Google

Tags: google-api

A want to query Google for the reviews I have made. I thought this could be done either through the Maps API or the Google+ API but I can't find the call to satisfy my need.

Is there any way this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

> We don't currently support returning reviews content in the Google+
>   API. However the top 5 reviews for any given place are available via
>   the Google Places API:
>
> http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/01/expanding-reviews-content-in-google.html
>   http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/07/add-flexible-search-and-google-reviews.html

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=260#c4)